# Displaying OLAP data in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, business-intelligence, olap-cube, dataviewwebpart

Is there any way to display the data of an OLAP cube in Sharepoint 2010? a Webpart?... I need to do it without excel services.

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Server Enterprise you can use Performance Point functionality. [MSDN best practices](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd285464%28v=office.14%29.aspx). It's not straightforward but possible. Otherwise you can use some 3rd party component.